# How to make multiple service calls in a loop in succession

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am iterating over an array and for each object in the array I need to make an api call. And then in the .done of the said call I need to update the object that was used to make the call as well as know when all calls have finished successfully.

```
applicants.forEach((applicant, index) => {
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    GetAppOverview(applicant.id).done((status) => {
        applicant.status = status;
    });
});
```

My ajax service looks like this.

```
module.exports = function(Id) {
  var defer = $.Deferred();
  $.ajax({
    url : url+'/'+id
    method : 'GET',
    headers : {
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json'   
    },
    success : function( data) {
      defer.resolve(data);
    },
    error : function( error ) {
        defer.reject(error);
    },
  });
  return defer.promise();   
};
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Errors? Unexpected behavior? Please explain what's happening and what is expected. Provide small working demo to reproduce bug, if possible.

Comment: @Pirate I want calls to be sequential so that I can set the status correctly. Right now, a call is made to GetAppOverView. But before the call is finished and status is set, the forEach will have already gone to next object. And when the first call is returned it sets the status for the second object. I am trying to use defer and promises to make it call one by one I suppose. My getAppOverviw returns a defer.resolve().

Comment: ok, that makes sense. What's in `GetAppOverView`. Could you post a code for that? May be you need `await`. [Check this out](https://petetasker.com/using-async-await-jquerys-ajax)

Comment: added my ajax service code.